# What is the need of memoization in python

Tags: python, memoization

I was reading this article

http://programmingzen.com/2009/05/18/memoization-in-ruby-and-python/

Actually can anyone please explain with example what will happen if i don't use it. I am not able to find which problem is solved by it. I just want to know two example where in one simple example without memoization and other with memoization so that i can see why we use it.

If example can be based on web realted stuff or Django that will be good so that i cam more understand it. I am not too techy in algorithms

Comment: If you have a function that, given a set of parameters will always return the same value then you can "remember" the result if you've already computed it so that you don't have to compute the result again later if the function takes a long time to do the computation.  Of course, you usually only want to remember a certain number of answers (within your memory constraints).

Comment: @mgilson how can function return the same result. any example? And if the result is same for every parameter then why can't i put that in a variable instead of function

Comment: for example:  `def square(x): return x*x` -- given a particular value of x, it will always return the same thing.  This is a trivial function.  Imagine something a lot more complex which takes lots of steps to complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explained simply, I'll put the question like this.  How many "E" characters are there in this block of text?

Now, how many "E" characters are there in the first block of text?

And now, how many "E" characters are there in the first block of text?

Finally, how many "E" characters are there in the first block of text?

If you were wondering, there were 9 "e"s and 2 "E"s in that first block.  By the second run through, you probably already memorized how many "E"s there were in the first block.  That's memoization for a `count` function/method over that block a text.

Answer (score 2):

Memoization caches (stores) the most recently used results of the function so it can retrieve them fast later. Basically if you a function is slow but has has the same results most of the time it can be helpful.

Comment: How will we know that how many items should need to be stored in the cache